# Ошибка "unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
slovar = {}
for i in range(n):
    str = input().split(' ', 1)
    slovar[str[0]] = str[1]
n1 = int(input())
for i in range(n1):
    slova = input()
    if slova not in slovar:
        print('Нет в словаре')
    else:
        print(slovar[slova]
```

вот такой текст программы, чекер выдаёт ошибку:

Вердикт Я.Контест: compilation-error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 125, in compile
    _optimize=optimize)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/temp/compiling/737de4ed-fa1f-456e-8be8-c59aaf933295", line 13

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/compiling/compilingScript", line 17, in <module>
    py_compile.compile(dst, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 129, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "/temp/compiling/737de4ed-fa1f-456e-8be8-c59aaf933295", line 13

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Ну как минимум у вас явно забыта скобка в последней строчке

Answer (score 2):

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Неожиданный конец файла во время анализа - EOF значит "End of File" (конец файла).

Это значит, что текст вашего кода окончился преждевременно - *компилятор еще что-то ожидал*, но ваш код окончился *перед тем, как это настало*.

Обычной причиной бывает, что вы *что-то начали а не закончили* - кавычку, апостроф, скобку (круглую, квадратную, фигурную): `"` `'` `(` `[` `{`.

Б башем случае ето `)` в конце вашей программы.