# Выдает ошибку "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python

> ```
> line 5
>     @bot.massage_handlers(commands=['start'])
>                                              ^
> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
> ```

Comment: См. [этот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792543/233990).

Comment: @Kromster, да, вы прав. Спасибо.